# ARRL numbered text ARL65 (ARL SIXTY FIVE) - what do the gaps stand for?

Tags: arrl

I am trying to understand ARRL numbered text messages and this one is not clear to me:

> ARL SIXTY FIVE: Arriving _______ on _______. Please arrange to meet me
> there.

The second gap seems to be intended for date, what does the first one stand for? Is it for a place or a time? If there is no time indicated, how can somebody arrange someone to meet the sender? If there is no place, where should they meet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Communication is a collaborative process, and the sender can fill in the blanks in whatever way seems most useful. The grammatical roles of the blanks don't have to be predefined.

ARL SIXTY FIVE DAYTON MAY 18 means "see you at Hamvention, contact me when you arrive and let's get dinner."

ARL SIXTY FIVE TUESDAY UNITED 119 means "please pick me up at O'Hare Terminal 5 around 2pm Tuesday."

ARL SIXTY FIVE MAIN STREET X TOMORROW AT HIGH NOON X BRING YOUR GUNS means it's an old west shootout.

Comment: Thanks, my profession is in database systems. I concentrated too much on predefined "data type" :-D